# Best way to sort a relation by a hash with sort values in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord, hash

Currently, I have a series of gift cards that have different statuses. Due to complex logic, these statuses are not persisted on the object. My goal is to order these gift cards by their status. This is my current implementation:

```
  @gift_cards.sort! do |a, b|
    comp = gc_sort_order[a.status] <=> gc_sort_order[b.status]
    comp.zero?? (b.expiration_date <=> a.expiration_date) : comp
  end
```

GiftCard#status retuns either expired redeeemd or active. Their 'sort weight' is determined by gc_sort_order defined thusly:

```
def gc_sort_order
  {
    active: 1,
    redeemed: 2,
    expired: 3
  }
end
```

However, this seems very clunky, and I'd like to refactor it but haven't come across a better solution as of yet. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@gift_cards.sort_by! { |gc| [-gc_sort_order[gc.status], gc.expiration_date] }.reverse
```

Comment: This would work, but the sort on expiration date is reversed.

e.g. `b.expiration_date <=> a.expiration_date`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Reverser
  attr_reader :v

  def initialize(v)
    @v = v
  end

  def self.[](v)
    new(v)
  end

  def <=>(other)
    other.v <=> @v
  end
end

# status ASC, expiration_date DESC
@gift_cards.sort_by! { |gc| [ gc_sort_order[gc.status], 
                              Reverser[gc.expiration_date] ] }
```